# woocommerce shortcode to display list product with the same category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a woocommerce short code to display a list of products with the same category?

I tried with:

```
[items per_page="6" columns="3" orderby="date" order="desc" category="10-20-percent"]
```

It did not work.

Comment: did I answer your question?

Answer (score 10):

Did you try these?

```
[product_categories number="14"]
```

or

```
[product_category category="snowpeak" per_page="12" columns="4" orderby="date" order="desc"]
```

Comment: [product_categories] displays categories, not products. [product_category] does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
[product_category category="categoryname"]
```